# animateMotion a path with marker-start and marker-end svg only

Tags: svg, svg-animate

is it possible to animate a path with `marker` elements? the path id in question is #orbit1.  the reason i created the `markers` is that they will be used multiple times.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1" viewBox="0 0 1500 1000">

 <defs>
  <marker id="arrowRight" viewBox="0 0 7.1 11.5" refX="5" refY="5.75"
   markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto-start-reverse"
   markerWidth="7.1" markerHeight="11.5">
   <polygon points="1,11.5 0,10.4 5.1,5.7 0,1 1,0 7.1,5.7" fill="#00897b"/>
  </marker>

  <marker id="circle" viewBox="0 0 6 6" refX="1" refY="3"
   markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto"
   markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6">
   <circle cx="3" cy="3" r="3" fill="#4caf50"/>
  </marker>
 </defs>

 <!-- arrowhead symbol -->
 <symbol>
  <path id="d_arrow1" fill="red" d="M-10-10L10 0l-20 10 2-10-2-10z" />
 </symbol>

 <!-- animateMotion defines the motion path animation -->
 <animateMotion xlink:href="#a1" begin="0s" dur="3s" rotate="auto" repeatCount="indefinite">
  <mpath xlink:href="#orbit1" />
  <!-- mpath = sub-element for the <animateMotion> element provides the ability to reference an external <path> element as the definition of a motion path -->
 </animateMotion>

 <animateMotion xlink:href="#a2" begin="0s" dur="3s" rotate="auto-reverse" keyPoints="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear" repeatCount="indefinite">
  <mpath xlink:href="#orbit2" />
 </animateMotion>


 <!-- arrow paths -->
 <path id="orbit2" d='M 365 400 A 370 200 0 0 1 1100 400' fill="none" stroke-width="3" style="stroke: green; stroke-dasharray: 50 818; stroke-dashoffset: 50"/>


 <!-- marker arrows -->
 <!-- orbit1 to be animated using mpath -->
 <path id="orbit1" d="M308.7 34.9C381.3 37.4 444.3 78 478.7 137.5" stroke="#4caf50" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="50 1000" stroke-dashoffset="50"
 marker-start="url(#circle)"
 marker-end="url(#arrowRight)"/>

 <!-- <animate> svg element used to animate an attribute or property of an element over time. it's normally inserted inside the element or referenced by the href attribute of the target element -->
 <animate id="anim1" xlink:href="#orbit1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="50" to="-960" dur="3s" begin="0s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 <!-- animate using the animateMotion definition above -->

 <animate id="anim2" xlink:href="#orbit2" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="-810" to="50" dur="3s" begin="0s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />

<!-- <use id="a1" xlink:href="#d_arrow1" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" />-->
   <use id="a2" xlink:href="#d_arrow1" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" />

</svg>
```

Comment: Since you have created a working example, what exactly do you think the problem is?

Comment: the path orbit1 has marker-start and end. i'm having difficulties animating them altogether (path plus the markers). the second example has no marker elements but has use elements. i am using marker elements because i'll be reusing those arrows in different rotations.  with marker elements, the positioning of the start and end are relative to the shape attached to. @RobertLongson